# Cosa significa "biacca" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, nouns

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Il mare era di piombo e il golfo lo stringeva come l’orlo di un crogiuolo. La massa densa delle nuvole nerissime ruzzolava arruffata fino a noi. Ma in fondo, tra mare e nuvole, c’era uno squarcio lungo che urtava contro l’ombra viola del Vesuvio, una ferita da cui grondava una **biacca** abbagliante. Restammo a lungo a guardare, gli abiti incollati dal vento.

Ho cercato il termine "biacca" in alcuni dizionari  e ho visto che può avere il significato di un colorante o pigmento di colore bianco ma, secondo me, questo non ha molto senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Sapreste spiegarme cosa vuol  dire "biacca" in questo passaggio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La descrizione usa immagini legate al piombo fuso. Il mare ne ha il colore, il golfo stringe il mare come in un crogiuolo. La biacca è «carbonato basico di piombo», e può diventare abbagliante visto il suo colore chiaro. L'immagine descrive quei momenti in cui tra mare scuro e cielo altrettanto scuro si vede una striscia di cielo da cui filtrano i raggi del sole, che sembrano ancora più abbaglianti nel contrasto.